Sequentially reading inputs of different types in Python
My program gets as input an integer, then a string, then another integer, all in the same line of input. In C++, I can read them from the standard input in one line, as follows:
int a; string b; int c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;

Moreover, I can easily read custom types like containers in the same way, if I define the >> operator correctly.
Is there a similar one-liner in Python? So far, the best I could come up with is the following ugly code:
a,b,c = [f(x) for f,x in zip((int,str,int),input().split())]


One alternative:
from operator import call

a,b,c = map(call, (int,str,int), input().split())

Attempt This Online!

That is indeed shorter than my solution. But still not as nice as the C++ solution.
